# Controlling content type in a Restful web service

Tags: ajax, json, rest, jquery

I am designing a Restful web service for an internal corporate application, and am curious how to merge JSON and "web content" requests.

The web application, like all good corporate applications, has a three-letter abbreviation that is reflected in the URL.  Let's say that this application's "call sign" is abc, and the users access it at the following URL

http://servername/abc

When the users access the root of the application we want to serve them up the main html page, the .js files (including jquery), the css, and the images.  Then, jquery will start to make AJAX calls back to the server.

What is the best way to handle these multiple content types?

http://servername/abc (returns contents of index.html)

http://servername/abc/javascript/jquery.js (returns a js file)

http://servername/abc/countries/de (returns JSON)

Should I split this into two web contexts?  Should I use the jquery contentType parameter in the ajax calls to explicitly specify JSON versus HTML versus something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the jQuery `contentType` is really just a parameter that sets your content-type header on your HTTP request to the server. It is always a best practice to set these for your AJAX calls.

Added:
Another good practice is to specifiy the `dataType` parameter as that will set the accept header on your HTTP request. This is useful for both GET and POST AJAX requests.

Most, if not all, web service frameworks (Rails, ASP.NET MVC, .NET WCF, etc..) have abilities to examine the headers of an HTTP request and determine what type of content to serve back

for example:
`application/json` in an HTTP Header would let your webservice know to return a JSON response instead of an HTML or XML response.

Some of the better ways that I have seen web apps organized for HTML/JSON serving is to make your standard routes always serve your HTML pages and resources, ie:

http://servername/abc

http://servername/abc/javascript/jquery.js

would do exactly as you have said. For your JSON (or even XML) responses, I see folks create a route that is explicity understood to serve back those types of responses, ie:

http://servername/api/abc/countries/de

the url route begins with an `/api/` which would always be understood to serve back a non-html JSON/XML response

this makes it pretty easy for your company to internally and externally understand that `/api/` routes are your JSON/XML responses. It also makes it easier to expose these methods to your customers externally should you want to do that as the infrastructure is there, you would just need to authenticate, etc... the requests.

Comment: The contentType parameter in JQuery is used only for posting data to the web server (HTTP POST). If you are attempting to request JSON data from the server (HTTP GET), you must use the dataType parameter in JQuery, which will set the HTTP Accept header.

Comment: Correct - added to the answer

Comment: Adding my 2 cents: In ASP.NET Web API, if a POST (or PUT or PATCH) is sent without setting the content-type, model binding would fail (in a typical setup) as the framework wouldn't know how to deserialize the posted content (adding here as this is the accepted answer and usually receives the most reads - I spent a lot of time figuring out why perfectly fine JSON posted to my API was resulting in a failure to be desirialized )

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is to use the standard [HTTP Accept Header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). In your ajax requests, you would specify this header to be application/json, and then all other web requests would include the browser's accept headers. Then, on the server side, you could use the Accept header to determine which content to serve.

If you use JQuery, then the Accept header will be set to application/json automatically if your dataType parameter is set to "json."